# Event evt and Event event

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand the difference between these two arguments, Event event and Event evt.

When do I use Event event and when do I use Event evt?

Thanks.

Comment: Event event just means it is of type Event and the name of the Event passed is event ... in the latter case you are just calling it evt instead ... you could call it Event fred if you really wanted

Comment: `event` and `evt` are just variable names for the parameters of type `Event`.  You could even use `e`, but I'd discourage it as it would make identifying the type in the code more difficult ;)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html

Answer (score 1):

`evt` and `event` are just names of variables. It could be any word, even `Event abc`, but it's better to use more clear to understand names.

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer, I thought they were predefined words.

Comment: If you like the answer, you can assept (green button on the left side), or upvote it.